# PHP Query and ORDER BY

Tags: php, sql-order-by

I got this code and need to sort the output by name:

```
$output = array();
while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_handle))
{
    $output[$res['_name']][] = $res['modell'];
}
```

Could anyone help me ? Thanks.

Comment: Wny don't you put `ORDER BY _name` in the SQL?

Comment: Using `ORDER BY` in MySQL is probably preferable to sorting in your PHP code.

Comment: Use `asort` sort in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use `ORDER BY` in Query

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY column_name;
```

OR

Use `asort` in PHP array

```
asort($output[$res['_name']]);
```

**Example**

```
<?php
$name_array = array("0"=>"cc", "1"=>"aa", "Joe"=>"bb");
asort($name_array);
print_r($name_array);
?>
```

**Result**

```
Array ( [1] => aa [Joe] => bb [0] => cc )
```

Refer http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_sort.asp

Answer (score 0):

can you please try and let me know if this helps

```
ksort($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

best way is use sorting in query, for example:

```
SELECT _name, modell FROM table_name ORDER BY _name ASC, modell ASC
```

This sort everything from A to Z. If you need results to sort from Z to A use DESC.

To sort the results in the field can be used, for example:

```
asort($output);
```

Overview table as sort fields:
http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: Link-only answers are not considered appropriate. Copy the relevant information to your answer, and use the link for supporting details.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the table using several functions that [php provide](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)
or you can modify your sql query add the `ORDER BY name`

Answer (score 0):

Use ORDER BY name in select query as follow :

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Name ORDER BY name
```

Thanks...